# Dockerfile builds correctly but ADD fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm rather new to Docker and I'm trying to make a simple Dockerfile that combines an alpine image with a python one.

This is what the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update &&\
    apk add -q --progress \
        bash \
        bats \
        curl \
        figlet \
        findutils \
        git \
        make \
        mc \
        nodejs \
        openssh \
        sed \
        wget \
        vim

ADD ./src/ /home/src/

WORKDIR /home/src/

FROM python:3.7.4-slim
```

When running:

```
docker build -t alp-py .
```

the image builds as normal.

When I run

```
docker run -it alp-py bash
```

I can access the bash, but when I cd to /home/ and ls, it shows an empty directory:

```
root@5fb77bbc81a1:/# cd home
root@5fb77bbc81a1:/home# ls
root@5fb77bbc81a1:/home#
```

I've alredy tried changing ADD to COPY and also trying:

```
CPOY . /home/src/
```

but nothing works.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the last line `FROM python:3.7.4-slim` won't discard all your changes above?

Comment: Only last FROM will be built out as final image in multistage build.

Comment: @SOFe I think not, Multi Stage building allows to merge Images right? I'll try anyway, maybe it is that!

Comment: The last line `FROM python:3.7.4-slim` will discard all the changes. Remove that if not required. Its not a correct way of using multi-stage builds.

Comment: Iirc it doesn't merge directly. You have to use something like ADD FROM. (I'll have to check again too)

Comment: Checked again, it should be `COPY --from`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "combining 2 images". You should see the images as different virtual machines (only for the purpose of understanding the concept - because they are more than that). You cannot combine them.

In your example you can start directly with the python image and install the tools you need on top of it:

```
FROM python:3.7.4-slim

RUN apt update &&\
    apt-get install -y \
        bash \
        bats \
        curl \
        figlet \
        findutils \
        git \
        make \
        mc \
        nodejs \
        openssh \
        sed \
        wget \
        vim

ADD ./src/ /home/src/

WORKDIR /home/src/
```

I didn't test if all the packages are available so you might want to so a bit of research to get them all in case you get errors.

When you use 2 FROM statements in your Dockerfile you are creating a multi-stage build. That is useful if you want to create a final image that doesn't contain your source code, but only binaries of your product (first stage build the source and the second only copies the binaries from the first one).